# Local dependency injection in angular.js failure

Tags: json, angularjs, dependency-injection, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to build a practice site based directly off the notorious [angular-phonecat](http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-5/app/) that would show a searchable list of a few text documents. I'm literally going step-by-step with the tutorial, just find-and-replacing the damn phones with my own text documents. It worked right up until the point I tried to use an $http dependency injection in the controller module ([AngularJS docs tutorial step 5](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)).

Here's what I got.

In my **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="workcatApp">
...
<body ng-controller="WorkListCtrl">
...
 <input ng-model="query" type="text" class="form-control" title="Enter keyword(s) to find" placeholder="Search...">
...
 <div>
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="dateCreated">Newest</option>
  </select> 
  <ul class="works">
    <li ng-repeat="work in works | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
       <span>{{work.name}}</span>
       <p>{{work.author}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
...
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my **js/controllers.js'**:

```
var workcatApp = angular.module('workcatApp', []);

workcatApp.controller('WorkListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('works/works.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.works = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'dateCreated';
}]);
```

And, finally, in my **works/works.json**:

```
[
{
    "dateCreated": 2010-09-26, 
    "id": "user_Jeff_CS35552Paper1", 
    "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg", 
    "name": "CS355 5%2 Paper #1", 
    "author": "userJeff"
},
...
```

In the browser I'm getting the selector to come through, but the {{work.name}} and {{work.author}} aren't translating into the angular magic. Any words of wisdom would be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you first define this work.json in the controller itself and then try to move this json to a file and if after that it doesn't work then you know for sure that the problem is in how you are fetching data from json.

Comment: Have you printed the `$scope.works` in the controller?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal what do you mean by printed? if by printed you mean putting a `console.log` statement to check if value to works is assigned then that should help too.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Have you added a log statement. Are `$scope.works` have values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, your view should be able to pick data using this type of assignment.

If it works then you can narrow down the problem to how you are making http call.
otherwise there is some other problem which I can look at.

```
workcatApp.controller('WorkListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
   function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.works = [{
       "dateCreated": 2010-09-26, 
       "id": "user_Jeff_CS35552Paper1", 
       "imageUrl": "img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg", 
       "name": "CS355 5%2 Paper #1", 
       "author": "userJeff"
      }]

   /*$http.get('works/works.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.works = data;
   });*/

   $scope.orderProp = 'dateCreated';
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I got it working. I think Angular was messing up my JSON (works.json) because of the "dateCreated" data-type. I had YYYY-MM-DD, and when I changed it to "YYYYMMDD" it works fine.